# problem using scp

Tags: scp

I issued an command on a local machine

scp -r download/ tim@foo.xxx.xxx.xxx

Then I checked at the remote foo.xxx.xxx.xxx and found under my home directory, there is nothing. Did scp transfer something? If yes, where are they?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a colon at the end, it should be `scp -r download/ tim@foo.xxx.xxx.xxx:`.  The colon shows you're transfering to a remote host and not just a local file called tim@foo.xxx.xxx.xxx.

Comment: ... so you should find a copy of all your files in a *local* directory named 'tim@foo.xxx.xxx.xxx' :)